# Distinct, ranged colors in google geochart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to make a google geochart with a range of values set as a specific, solid color.

Example:
number of cookies-
0-10: red
11-20: yellow
21-30:green

I'm trying to use the colorAxis.values object to do this like this:

```
var options = {
        colorAxis: {values:[0, 10], colors:['red', 'red'],
                    values:[11, 20], colors:['yellow', 'yellow'],
                    values:[21, 30], colors:['green', 'green']}
                  };
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying here?

Answer (score 3):

Use a single `values` array and a single `colors` array:

```
colorAxis: {
    values:[0, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30],
    colors:['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'green']
}
```